# Firebase not entering observation block

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's a code snippet I have before a user logs into my app. The snippet fetches existing usernames and adds it into a dictionary. The problem is it does not seem to even enter the line `print("OBSERVING")`. I am not sure what to do as the debugger is not showing any issues. It just skips this block entirely. The block works on my `iPhone 6S Plus 10.2.1` but it is not working on my `iPhone 6s 10.3.1.` Updated my XCode to the latest and Firebase as well.

```
reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print("OBSERVING")

        if let usernameList = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: String]]{
            self.usernames = usernameList
            completionHandlerForLoading(true)
        }else{
            completionHandlerForLoading(false)
        }
    })
```

Rules set for Firebase are open. Auth is not needed to enter as well.

Edit: Snippet of reference creation
[image]

[image]

[image]

Snippet of Firebase
[image]

**UPDATE:**
It's working after I successfully sign into the app once (AUTH Ignites succesfully). And then when I run this app again to check for usernames when logged out it successfully does as stated. Now the question is how to do this without authorizing first?

MY FIRBase Rules are open.

Comment: Show us ur db screenshot and how do u create reference

Comment: What is Database? Is it FIRDatabase?

Comment: Add code with calling LoadUsernames

Comment: @VladPulichev Database is Firebase 4's new version of calling FIRDatabase. Updated with the function stack leading to the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Does "ENTERED" print?

Comment: @VladPulichev yes, "ENTERED" prints and then the function never returns because none of the handlers are being completed.

Comment: wait. "OBSERVING" prints too?

Comment: @VladPulichev nope, skips right over that block.

Comment: Try changing .value to .childAdded

Comment: Has it helped?:)

Comment: @VladPulichev It did not work :(

Comment: And "OBSERVING" still not appear?

Comment: @VladPulichev Still does not appear

Comment: Do you work with breakpoint? I mean, .observe works async.

Comment: @VladPulichev yet to learn to use breakpoint. I have placed one on the line of the code "reference.observe" sits

Comment: Try to remove all breakpoints. And let it work some time. And check console prints. Idk, why it's not working:(

Comment: @VladPulichev okay no problem. I am not sure why its skipping the reference. I will keep messing around and post a solution when I find one. It is an interesting test case.

Comment: If you can, pls, mention me in comment, if you will find. Favorited btw

Comment: @VladPulichev will do!

Comment: @VladPulichev Got it to work after signing into the app once. Then when I restart the app its as if I "woke up" firebase. Posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188405/firebase-not-observing-until-accessed-once

Comment: Thanks! I will check