# Firebase not observing until accessed once

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase is configured in `APPDelegate`.

Read is set to `.true` in rules.

But, before I have a user sign into my application, I am checking for usernames, within a separate table of my Firebase DB. It would skip the observation block entirely, until I forced signed-in into another already created account of mine. And then when I would re-build the application the block is no longer skipped and actually accesses the table.

How do I "Wake Up" Firebase when I run the app on a fresh device, so I can check for usernames without having to log onto the app with an existing account before hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to reconsider how the app is structured.

If you are checking for usernames before being authenticated that means the node is exposed and anyone can grab a copy of all the usernames. Obviously that in itself may not be a huge issue but if your users decide to use an email, whoever grabs the list has a instant list they can spam to.

When you add *any* observer to a node, that node is read once as soon as the observer is added. When you app starts you can use .childAdded to iterate over an existing node to pre-load some data, a grocery list for example, and then any new grociees added after that will be sent your your app via an event.

Likewise a .value event will read in an entire node and leave an observer attached for *any* future events.

The username issue is tricky and the way you are doing is now is probably going to get you in trouble in the long run.

A better way is to leverage [Firebase Authentication.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth)

Firebase handles all of the usernames and passwords for you. It's very powerful and flexible and avoids the issues you are encountering. It will let you know if user names exist or not, it will do password reset emails and you can manage users from the Firebase Console. It's the way to go.

If you want to add username functionality it can be pretty easily done by adding a username or nickname node to the /users node

```
/users
   uid_0
    email: "bill@email.com"
    username: "bill_the_cat"
   uid_1
    email: "clark@email.com"
    username: "superman"
```

Once the user authenticates using Firebase Authentication, from there forward any time the user info needs to be displayed in the app, simply look up the uid that you need (uid_1) and grab the username node (superman) for display.

Comment: I utilize firebase auth. But I guess I was also trying to add a username feature on top of utilizing an email to authenticate. "This the username entered gets matched with an email in the table which then it uses to authenticate" is there any way to be able to add unique usernames as a property to firebase Auth?

Comment: @NashEquilibrium No you cannot add random properties to Firebase user storage and Yes, you could pretty easily add username functionality. It would happen after the user authenticates with Firebase Authentication. You could think of it as a 'nickname' for the user where users could interact with each other via the nickname instead of their authentication email. I added a little blurb to my answer to give you a starting point. You can also leverage some of the user properties such as displayName, but for this use case, I think the username node is the way to go.

Comment: Darn, If only there was a way to do this during registration! haha. It's okay. Thank you so much for the help Jay.

Comment: @NashEquilibrium Agreed! If my answer helped you, please accept it so other can benefit as well.